# Should I run mining on Private Test Network?

Tags: mining, private-blockchain

I strongly believed that pending transactions can not be approved and included into a block without mining, isn't it? But now, I'm into confusion about this. One of my customers said that there should not be any mining processes on a private test network.

So, for example, if I preallocate Ether in Genesis block and run the network without mining, will I be able to send transactions, create contracts?

Please, clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pending transactions can not be approved and included into a block without mining, isn't it?

Yes. Mining is required to arrange transactions into blocks and add blocks to the blockchain.

> if I preallocate Ether in Genesis block and run the network without mining, will I be able to send transactions, create contracts?

You can pre-allocate ether using the genesis block. However, even with this ether, you can only initiate transactions and create contracts. To confirm/validate those transactions and to deploy contracts to the blockchain, **you need to have at least one miner**.